# Git clone works but fetch fails using plink SSH

Tags: git, ssh

Git clone works fine without asking for any ssh info using plink.exe. However git fetch fails with Permission denied (publickey). GIT_SSH is set to plink.exe

Answer (score 0):

Always use the "git" user
All connections, including those for remote URLs, must be made as the "git" user. If you try to connect with your GitHub username, it will fail:

$ ssh -T GITHUB-USERNAME@github.com

> Permission denied (publickey).
> If your connection failed and you're using a remote URL with your GitHub username, you can change the remote URL to use the "git" user.

You should verify your connection by typing:

$ ssh -T git@github.com

> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated...

refer link: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey